# Seeking References for Mediation and SEM Best Practices

Tags: r, references, structural-equation-modeling, mediation, lavaan

**Preamble**

Recently, a colleague approached me with a dataset$^1$ that they wanted to use to compare several competing mediation models using structural equation modeling (SEM). The models are simple, e.g., `X -> Y -> Z`, and everything has been going well using `lavaan`.

**Question**

I know a fair amount about confirmatory factor analysis (CFA), though know next to nothing about the current best practices as it concerns mediation and SEM. Could someone point me to some good up to date references? I am not so much looking for an "introduction" but articles covering best practices. Thanks!

$^1$ The characteristics of my data set are not particularly important to my question, though if it helps each of the three factors are measured with 4 Likert scale items (i.e., 12 items total) with 5 response options each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think probably my favorite book on this topic, which has a very recent edition from 2023, is [Kline's book](https://www.guilford.com/books/Principles-and-Practice-of-Structural-Equation-Modeling/Rex-Kline/9781462551910) on SEM. There are a lot of great chapters and I would say its a lot less mathy and more practical compared to other SEM books I have read. Page 40 of his text, for example, has this very long checklist for writing up results:

[image]

Chapter 20 of his book specifically details mediation, including important topics like *the mediation myth*, types of mediation models, effect sizes for indirect effects, and many other topics relevant to mediation. I would read the whole book before diving into that, paying particular attention to if you have gaps in your knowledge in the beginning sections (he brilliantly has sections for regression, item theory, etc. for you to check your understanding and shore up if lacking).

Specific to your question but true of all modeling, one can compare any number of infinite models in SEM. The question becomes which are theoretically and empirically defensible, all of which should be considered a priori and not after the data is collected.

As a final note, since you are specifically using R and `lavaan`, you may also appreciate [Beaujean's book](https://www.routledge.com/Latent-Variable-Modeling-Using-R-A-Step-by-Step-Guide/Beaujean/p/book/9781848726994) on modeling SEM in R, which is more about the practical syntax-driven aspects than the general topic of SEM. [Bollen's text](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118619179) is pretty decent too, particularly if you want to know more about some of the underlying math of SEM, but it is also quite old and may not be what you're looking for given your query.